# How can I bypass error 111 MySQL in PHP connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I have bought a database MySQL to use on my domain/host.
I can connect to the database via wampserver (localhost) without problems.
But when I am trying to connect to the host website it gives me an error.

> Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql-******.net' (111 "Connection refused")

My code:

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql-*********.net";
$username = "username8954";
$password = "dolphyn1235";
$dbname   = "animals";
$dbServerPort = "26313";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $dbServerPort);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What is "mysql-*********.net" supposed to be? It doesn't seem like a real server. You need to determine the right values to use for your hosting provider, they will not be the same as your local connection.

Comment: I hide that info.
Theres nothing wrong with servername user or password or even port.
Because as I said I can connect it via wamp with the same code

Comment: Your server, username, password, database name and port will all be different between local and hosted database services.

Comment: Either MySql is not running on that server, or a firewall on the server or elsewhere is blocking you. It is unusual for a MySQL server to be accessible from the public internet. Usually you need to use an SSH tunnel to access it.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - That might be a small bit of a rabbit hole, chances are higher that they are using the wrong details (notice their non-standard port and the reference to "it worked locally")

Comment: There are many possible causes for "Connection Refused" errors. The connection can fail at many points between the client and server. There's a guide for troubleshooting that lists many possible causes in the MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Check in your MySQL Server configuration files (my.cnf), find `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` then comment them with `#` at the begining of the line. and then restar your MySQL.